# How convert Html 5 canvas to image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have created html 5 canvas using the code below.

```js
var p1 = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    $.post('<?= Url('
      sheet / drowhole ')?>', {
        id: <?= $row - > id ?>
      }, function() {}).done(function(data) {
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      var deep = data.end[(data.end.length - 1)];
      var c = document.getElementById("hole");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 850);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
      ctx.strokeRect(100, 25, 200, 800);
      drowMatiral(ctx, data, deep);
      droArrow(ctx, data, deep);
      drowText(ctx, data, deep);
      canvesRwritSideDraw(ctx, data, deep);
      waterLavel(ctx, data, deep);
      resolve(c);
    });
  });
p1.then(function(c) {

});

function drowText(ctx, data, deep) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.material.length; i++) {
    ctx.font = "12px Times New Roman";
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillText(data.start[i] + " m", 40, (25 + data.start[i] * 800 / deep));
    ctx.fillText(data.end[i] + " m", 40, (25 + data.end[i] * 800 / deep));
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.font = "15px bold Times New Roman";
    ctx.fillText(data.material[i], 10, ((((data.end[i] - data.start[i]) / deep) * 800 / 2) + 29) + (data.start[i] / deep) * 800);
  }
}

function waterLavel(ctx, data, deep) {
  var lineJoin = ['round'];
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, ((data.water_lavel / deep) * 800) + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(400, ((data.water_lavel / deep) * 800) + 25);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#66ffff';
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.stroke();

}

function droArrow(ctx, data, deep) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.material.length; i++) {
    var lineJoin = ['round'];
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.4;
    ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(90, (data.start[i] / deep) * 800 + 25);
    ctx.lineTo(80, (data.start[i] / deep) * 800 + 25);
    ctx.lineTo(80, ((((data.end[i])) - (data.end[i] - data.start[i]) / 2) / deep) * 800 + 23);
    ctx.lineTo(76, ((((data.end[i])) - (data.end[i] - data.start[i]) / 2) / deep) * 800 + 25);
    ctx.lineTo(80, ((((data.end[i])) - (data.end[i] - data.start[i]) / 2) / deep) * 800 + 27);
    ctx.lineTo(80, (((data.end[i])) / deep) * 800 + 25);
    ctx.lineTo(90, (((data.end[i])) / deep) * 800 + 25);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function drowMatiral(ctx, data, deep) {

  var imgs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.material.length; i++) {
    imgs[i] = new Image();
    imgs[i].src = '<?= Url('
    ');?>/' + data.img[i];
    imgs[i].startingPoingY = (data.start[i] * 800 / deep) + 25;
    imgs[i].deep = (data.end[i] - data.start[i]) * 800 / deep;
    imgs[i].onload = (function() {
      var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(this, 'repeat');
      ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
      ctx.fillRect(100, this.startingPoingY, 100, this.deep);

    });
  }

}

function canvesRwritSideDraw(ctx, data, deep) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)";
  ctx.fillRect(200, 25, 100, Math.max.apply(Math, data.field) * 800 / deep);
  ctx.font = "12px Times New Roman";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.fillText('0 m', 340, 25);
  var lineJoin = ['round'];
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.4;
  ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 25);
  ctx.lineTo(330, 25);
  ctx.stroke();
  var x = deep / 10;
  var x1 = deep / 20;
  var x2 = deep / 100;
  for (var j = 0; x2 < deep; j++) {

    ctx.font = "12px Times New Roman";
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillText(x.toFixed(2) + ' m', 340, (x * 800 / deep) + 25);

    var lineJoin = ['round'];
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.4;
    ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(280, 25 + (x * 800 / deep));
    ctx.lineTo(330, 25 + (x * 800 / deep));
    ctx.stroke();
    var lineJoin = ['round'];
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.4;
    ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0]
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(300, 25 + (x1 * 800 / deep));
    ctx.lineTo(330, 25 + (x1 * 800 / deep));
    ctx.stroke();

    var lineJoin = ['round'];
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.4;
    ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0]
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(300, 25 + (x2 * 800 / deep));
    ctx.lineTo(310, 25 + (x2 * 800 / deep));
    ctx.stroke();
    x = x + deep / 10;
    x1 = x1 + deep / 20;
    x2 = x2 + deep / 100;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < data.field.length; i++) {
    var lineJoin = ['round'];
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.3;
    ctx.lineJoin = lineJoin[0];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200, (data.field[i] * 800 / deep) + 25);
    ctx.lineTo(300, (data.field[i] * 800 / deep) + 25);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}
```

Normal view of the canvas:

[image: This is normal view of the canvas.]

I can download this canvas as image using below code .

```
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
  link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
  link.download = filename;
}
```

Image Download is perfect.

but when I convert this canvas as image some part are missed.  I use the code below to convert:

```
p1.then(function (c){
  var imgObj    = c.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.write('<img src="'+imgObj+'"/>');
});
```

This is the converted image.

[image: Converted image]

Please tell me how to convert the canvas to image.

Comment: It is NEVER a good idea to document.write anything after load. The page including script is wiped. Perhaps the conversion was not finished when the document.write executed. Instead insert it into a container using innerHTML or .html()

Comment: Thanx for reply .
 i need to convert this canvas to image for print this Html page and convert this html page as pdf .

Comment: Did it improve when you changed the document.write?

Comment: no. what is the best method convert this canvas to image.
my purposes are   i need to print this html page  with canvas  and convert this html page with canvas to pdf

Comment: I didn't read the whole code but drawMatiral is asynchronous, it will draw your images only in their onload event, and will continue to the end of the workflow before it happend. So what you need is to preload your images, then start the workflow by only calling ctx.drawImage(preloadedImage [i],x,y). This way all will be drawn in correct order and your toDataURL will be called after the images has been drawn.